# vtk6.3 link error:no override found for 'vtkRenderWindow'

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I hava built vtk6.3 with qt5.5 on ubuntu 64bit,and I open an example with qtcreator.Build it,then link error occur:

> Generic Warning: In /VTK/Rendering/Core/vtkRenderWindow.cxx, line 40
>   Error: no override found for 'vtkRenderWindow'.

The line 40 with doc:

`//Use the vtkAbstractObjectFactoryNewMacro to allow the object factory overrides.
vtkAbstractObjectFactoryNewMacro(vtkRenderWindow)`

I google for this problem,almost all explanation is about this [link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Build_System_Migration#How_Implementation_Modules_Are_Initialized),it seems I must add this macro in my cpp file to enable the factory methord:

`include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingWindow)`

But I got another error:

`` error: undefined reference to `vtkRenderingWindow_AutoInit_Construct()'
error: undefined reference to `vtkRenderingWindow_AutoInit_Destruct()' ``

I can't find any built library define these symbols,google it and I got almost nothing.I am new to vtk,can anyone give some help?

Answer (score 1):

Use `VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL)` instead of `VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingWindow)`. It works for me.

Comment: Hi, this did not seem to work for me. I am getting an issue that was similar to here: https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/1553 I cannot seem to get their solution to work. I don't want to have to use a CMakeFile. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

this is an old thread, but just in case...
If you are not using cmake with your VTK project you may run into the link "error: undefined reference to".
How can you find out the right library out of the (v6.1: 377) vtk libraries available, when the documentation gives no hint?
Solution: in headers there usually is an EXPORT macro like this:

```
class VTKCOMMONDATAMODEL_EXPORT vtkCellArray
```

this gives a hint for the library: in this case libvtkCommonDataModel

In regardto the problem with

```
undefined reference to `vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct()'
```

I had used the macro

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2)
```

Solution: on my system there is only a libvtkRenderingOpenGL. So change the VTK_MODULE_INIT line and add linker option -lvtkRenderingOpenGL to the command.