# Error with vtkRenderer

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm new to vtk, so I started by building vtk 8.1.1 with CMake and Visual Studio 2017, with the default options and the examples.

Many of the examples runs fine, but some of them gives an error:

[image]

This one is the CreateTree example, but the HelloWorld gives the same error.

I don't know if it has something to do with [this issue](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17261).

I've also tried the solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770279/vtk6-3-link-errorno-override-found-for-vtkrenderwindow) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029151/no-override-found-for-vtkrenderer-vtkrenderwindow). But when I add

```
#include <vtkAutoInit.h>
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2);
```

right after all the includes, Visual Studio gives me this error:

1>CreateTree.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct(void)" (?vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Construct@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit::vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit(void)" (??0vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit@@QAE@XZ)

1>CreateTree.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Destruct(void)" (?vtkRenderingOpenGL2_AutoInit_Destruct@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit::~vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit(void)" (??1vtkRenderingOpenGL2_ModuleInit@@QAE@XZ)

1>C:\vtkSource\bin\bin\Debug\CreateTree.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals

if I try `VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingWindow)` or `VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL)` I get the same errors.

Also, examples like Delaunay3D only open a window that closes so fast I can't even see what it does have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding the following line

```
vtkRendering${VTK_RENDERING_BACKEND}
```

to the `set(VTK_Modules ...)` command in the `CMakeLists.txt` for the `HelloWorld` or `CreateTree` projects just like it is suggested in [the link you posted](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/issues/17261).

EDIT

Just to expand the explanation for beginners, the `CMakeLists.txt` is the path `VTK-8.1.1\Examples\Infovis\Cxx`. And the file should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Because the Gitlab issue had the tags "closed" and "merged" I thought it was a solved issue, and downloading the latest version of vtk would not have this problem. Anyway, I didn't know which CMakeLists.txt to look for. The Delaunay example doesn't work yet, I will post another question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Yes, you should add that line to `CMakeLists.txt` that defines the target (`add_executable(TreeTarget)`) for the specific example. Generally, it is the `CMakeLists.txt` that is closest to the source code file in the directory hierarchy.