# vtk: Modelling examples not working (Delaunay3D, finance etc)

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm new to vtk, and I've succesfully built vtk 8.1.1 from source, using Cmake and Visual Studio 2017, with the default options and examples.

I've already [solved an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51796656/error-with-vtkrenderer) with the Infovis folder examples.

Now, I'm trying to run the examples from the Modelling folder:

[image]

The problem is that when I try to run these examples, it opens a window that closes so fast I can't even see what it says, so I have no clue about the error.

The Delaunay3D.cxx file begins with these comments:

```
`// Delaunay3D
// Usage: Delaunay3D InputFile(.vtp) OutputFile(.vtu)
//        where
//        InputFile is an XML PolyData file with extension .vtp
//        OutputFile is an XML Unstructured Grid file with extension .vtu
`
```

So it looks like I need external data files, and the same is true for the other examples. But, where do I get these files, and where do I place them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the examples in the source files are not complete i.e. as you found out, some of them require external input files which may be missing or mistakes in CMakeLists.txt etc. In the parent folder of the folder that you have attached screenshot of (i.e. the `Modelling` directory) there is also a folder for Python examples. In that folder, there is a `Delaunay3D.py` file which creates random points as input instead of reading them from file. So you can do the same. The names and signatures of functions in Python and C++ are the same by modifying the `Delaunay3D.cxx` code or adding some code in the `TestDelaunay3D.cxx`. But there is no such file for the finance example, unfortunately.

I find it useful to use VTK code along with [Paraview](https://www.paraview.org/). Paraview is built on top of VTK. It has most of the VTK filters available through the GUI. In Paraview you can also create some data and save it to file using `File->Save Data`. You can then use that as input for the examples. Once you become familiar with VTK file types and VTK sources, generating data does not require a lot of code. So you can do it yourself by modifying any of the example code (like it is done in the `Delaunay3D.py`).

About where to place the input files, in this particular case you can place them anywhere but when you run the executable that was built, you must enter the path of the input file correctly on the command line.

**Updates based on comments:**

1. The Python wrappers provide almost complete features available with the C++ version. The exceptions are noted [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/vtk/vtk/blob/master/Wrapping/Python/README.md). If you decide to use VTK Python then a good resource to read is the [VTK Numpy interface](https://blog.kitware.com/improved-vtk-numpy-integration/).
2. Paraview implements a majority of VTK filters and sources. So it can do a lot of creation and modification of geometries. In addition, you can use [programmable filters and sources](https://www.paraview.org/Wiki/Python_Programmable_Filter) for doing things which are not available through Gui. In the programmable filters you can write any Python script which can import vtk and use all its functionality.
3. But if for your use case you only need a subset of the functionality Paraview provides then you may want to write your own GUI.

Comment: Thanks for your help Amit, I'll check it later when I get home! Do you think it is better to use vtk with Python? I've downloaded Anaconda (https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/) and tried some python examples (including Delaunay) and they work, and all of this without using Cmake or VS. Does vtk with Python lacks some of the features from C++ core version?

Comment: About Paraview, I haven't tried yet, but I will, and it is always cited in vtk discussions. My intention is to make a 3D geological modelling software, where the user will be able to create and modify geometry. I began with vtk because I've thought Paraview is only for visualization, is it correct? There is already [Paraview Geo](https://sites.google.com/a/objectivity.ca/paraviewgeo/downloads/paraviewgeo-executables), but it seems the [project is dead](https://github.com/ObjectivitySRC/ParaViewGeo)...

Comment: You are welcome! I have added more information in the answer. I use both C++ and Python versions of VTK. For some short scripting on small data I prefer using Python. But for some heavy work I would use C++.

Comment: I've been playing with vkt using Python (using Spyder and the Anaconda distribution). One of the disadvantages is that you cannot access protected members of a class even if you make a derived sub class in Python, right? This can be done in C++.

Comment: I think it depends on the VTK developers. They control what part of the C++ implementation of VTK to expose to Python Wrappers. So what you say may be true.